# The bar in my Scrollbar is missing from my python program using Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a window to display data stored inside dictionaries. I have created a canvas, scrollbar and a frame inside the canvas to place my Text widgets to display the information. When I execute my code the layout is just as I want it, but the bar is missing from the scroll bar and I can't figure out why. Here is my code for the GUI portion:

```
root = Tk()

# create top part
top=Frame(root)
# create a canvas to scroll
holder = Canvas(top)
# create scroll bar
scroll = Scrollbar(top, orient=VERTICAL, command=holder.yview)
# configure scrollbar for canvas
holder.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
holder.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: holder.configure(scrollregion=holder.bbox("all")))
# create frame for content inside canvas and add it to the canvas
content = Frame(holder, relief=RAISED)
holder.create_window(0, 0, window=content, anchor='nw')
# create bottom part
bottom = Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=18)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=50)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
holder.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
content.pack(fill=X)
top.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
bottom.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

num=0
for site in sites:
    temp=Text(content, height = 5)
    temp.configure(state= DISABLED)
    temp.pack(fill=X, side=TOP, padx= 5, pady= 5)
    siteBoxes.append(temp)
    num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

here is a screenshot of what the result looks like
[Program GUI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ0U2.png)

there are that many text boxes there just to test the scrollbar, the data display within the Text widgets haven't been written yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found the culprit, it was the line content.pack(fill=X), since I already have it in the window of the canvas this line of code was causing the issue. How ever now the Text widget no longer spans all of the horizontal space, how would I fix this issue while still using .create_window()?